# Can Google Calendar send e-mail reminders to a non-Gmail address?

Tags: google-calendar, notifications

Google Calendar can send reminders of my events to my Gmail inbox.

Is it possible to tell Google Calendar to send those e-mail reminders to a different e-mail address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'll find that Google Calendar sends the reminder to the Google account that owns the calendar.

So if you make a Google account (e.g., with a product like Blogger) that has an account name that looks like a non-Google email address (e.g., you@outlook.com) and an associated primary email address which is that address, then reminders for events set up in that account's calendar are sent to the non-Google email address.

Another approach, if your calendar is already set up in your Google account that's named with a Gmail address, might just to be use a forwarding rule in Gmail to send reminders on.  To do this:

1. Add your non-Gmail address as a forwarding address, verify it - and leave forwarding disabled in general
2. Add a filter, choosing all messages filtering the messages from calendar-notification@google.com  and forwarding them to your non-Gmail address.

Comment: Approach 2 would be useful if one could discover what would be "_the words that would identify a reminder message_".

Comment: It turns out that filtering the messages from _calendar-notification@google.com_ would do the trick. Please, consider adding that to your answer.

Comment: @bruno I used Matches: from:(calendar-notification@google.com) "Calendar [NAME OF CALENDAR]"

Answer (score 1):

All types of Google Calendar reminders are sent only to the Calendar event owner.

If you invited a guest to your event and he accepted the invitation and added the event to his calendar, he will get a reminder according to his calendar default behavior.

If this is not the behavior you are looking for, you might want to try [Un4gettable](http://www.un.4gettable.com).

It is

> a free Google Calendar add-on that sends text message (SMS) Reminders to clients.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the Contact email of your Google account:

- Navigate to your Google account settings (from most Google pages in your browser: Click on your profile picture in the top right, then ''My Account'').
- In the ''Personal info & privacy settings'' pane, click ''Your personal info''.
- Click ''Email''.
- Click ''Contact email''.
- Select the e-mail address where you want to receive your notifications. If it's not there, add it first.

However, this will send a lot of communication from Google that used to come to your gmail account to that new address.

Comment: If anyone knows how to do this for Google Calendar specfically, that would be great.